# How can I set a certain predicate for the result of a function to true?

Tags: expression-test

I have an object called `f` (basically a vector of functions) and a predicate called `MemberQR`(actually its with subscript R).

`MemberQR[f]:=True` I.e. I set the predicate to true.

Now I want to apply a Transformation on `f`, and the result still should have the predicate set to `True`.

So for `fooFunction[f_?MemberQR]:= 2 f;` the result should also yield true when tested for MemberQR.

Of course, I do not know what exactly the components of `f` are, they might be different each time.

I have tried the use of `%` but was not sucessful. `fooFunction` is not supposed to produce output, it just transforms `f`.

Comment: You may represent your object by a list. The first n elements are your functions, and the last element the predicate. Then you must define  `MemberQR` and `fooFunction` so that they take this object as input. Note, if you want to define  `MemberQR[f_]` so that it changes `f`, you must use the attribute `HoldFirst` or `HoldAll`. More niftly, you may even define an indexed variable like: `myObject[fun1,fun2,..,predicate]`

Comment: Can you just set another rule for MemberQR as a side effect of fooFunction? eg `fooFunction[f_?MemberQR] := Module[{res = 2 f}, MemberQR[res] = True; res]`

Comment: @DanielHuber I cannot modify 'f', I can only modify fooFunction.

Comment: @SimonWoods your suggestion looks good, I will see, if I can modify this for my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Simon Woods suggested,

```
fooFunction[f_?MemberQR] := Module[{res = 2 f}, MemberQR[res] = True; res]
```

works.

Answer (score 0):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
```

Use [`TagSetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html) to associate the property with `f`

```
MemberQR /: MemberQR[f] := True;

fooFunction[g_?MemberQR] := 2 g;
```

Testing

```
fooFunction /@ {f, g}

(* {2 f, fooFunction[g]} *)
```

**EDIT:**

```
MemberQR /: MemberQR[fooFunction[f_?MemberQR]] := True

MemberQR[fooFunction[#]] & /@ {f, g}

(* {True, MemberQR[fooFunction[g]]} *)
```

Comment: Does not work for me. MemberQR[2f] is not True.

Comment: That is not the problem that you described. If you also want to handle multiples of `f` use `MemberQR /: MemberQR[a_. * f] := True;`

Comment: What I tried to express in the question post is, that `MemberQR[fooFunction[f]]` should be true, whenever `MemberQR[f]` is true.